# How to send a TCP buffer with different element sizes?

Tags: c++, tcp

I am trying to send a 24 bit message between a TCP server and client.

So I have

```
uint8_t id = 5;
unint16_t num = 4000;
```

So what would be a way to send them in a TCP buffer? I know I need to convert the uint16_t into network byte order and i would not need to do that for the uint8_t.

The message I am sending has to be able to be unpaced with one of these calls as well

```
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);
uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);
uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);
uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
```

The client is expecting a message that is comprised of a 8 bit character followed by a 16 bit number. I cannot change this so I have to work around it some how. The client will be using the above functions to convert the message as well.

As far as I know this cannot be done using one buffer. Have I over looked something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can marshall your data together by copying it into a single flat byte-buffer, like this:

```
uint8_t id = 5;
uint16_t num = 4000;
uint16_t beVal16 = htons(num);
unsigned char flatbuf[sizeof(id)+sizeof(beVal16)];
memcpy(&flatbuf[0], &id, sizeof(id));
memcpy(&flatbuf[sizeof(id)], &beVal16, sizeof(beVal16));
int numBytesSent = send(theSocketFD, flatbuf, sizeof(flatbuf), 0);
```

... and then do the reverse on the receiving side:

```
uint8_8 id;
uint16_t beVal16;
unsigned char flatbuf[sizeof(id)+sizeof(beVal16)];
int numBytesReceived = recv(theSocketFD, flatbuf, sizeof(flatbuf), 0);
if (numBytesReceived == sizeof(flatbuf))
{
   memcpy(&id, &flatbuf[0], sizeof(id));
   memcpy(&beVal16, &flatbuf[sizeof(id)], sizeof(beVal16));
   uint16_t num = ntohs(beVal16);

   printf("received num=%u id=%u\n", num, id);
}
else {/* handle error or partial-buffer-receive, omitted here */}
```

Comment: I guess the concept is the same but the client is in C++ and the server is in Python. I didn't tag the question properly. It looks like that takes care of the sending really well though.

Comment: For doing the receive logic in Python, check out the python struck.unpack() method, it is very useful for that sort of thing.

Comment: Err, that would be struct.unpack()  (cursed autocorrect!)

Answer (score 1):

You can place the data in a single buffer like this:

```
uint8_t id = 5;
unint16_t num = 4000

...
uint8_t buf[3];
buf[0] = id;
//pack num in network byte order:
buf[1] = (num & 0xff00) >> 8;
buf[2] = num & 0xff;

int rc = write(tcpsock, buf, sizeof buf);
//check rc
```

Or you could also accomplish it with this, slightly less efficient 
since it performs two write calls:

```
int rc = write(tcpsock, &id, sizeof id);
int num_net = htons(num);
rc = write(tcpsock, &num_net sizeof num_net);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The client is expecting a message that is comprised of a 8 bit character followed by a 16 bit number.

TCP is a streaming transport, it has no concept of messages.  You could simply send the two values individually:

```
uint8_t id = 5;
send(sckt, &id, sizeof(id), 0);

uint16_t num = htons(4000);
send(sckt, &num, sizeof(num), 0);
```

The peer will receive 3 bytes in the correct order. That is guaranteed by TCP.  The receiver could read 1 byte followed by 2 bytes, or read 3 bytes at one time, or even read 1 byte three times. TCP does not care.

> As far as I know this cannot be done using one buffer.

Of course it can.

For starters, if Send Coalescing via the [Nagle algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) is enabled (which it is by default), the socket will buffer small sends and transmit them in more efficient packets.  So the two `send` calls above will very likely be transmitted together.

But, if you don't want to rely on that, you could simply define a `struct` to hold the values, and then send that:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // or equivalent
struct pktmsg
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint16_t num;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

pktmsg msg;
msg.id = 5;
msg.num = htons(4000);
send(sckt, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `writev()`, the 'gathering write' call.

Comment: That seems more convenient. So it will automatically write to two separate buffers because they are different sizes then?

Comment: It will automatically write *from* one, two, or more buffers of the same or different sizes, whatever you want. No data copying required.

Comment: Note that `writev()` is not a portable function, but would be easy to manually implement an equivalent function on platforms that do not have it.